# Laravel how to query pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, pivot-table

I have three models : **Album**, **Author**, **Contribution**

There's a many-to-many relationship with Album and Author

```php
// Album model

function authors()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Author::class);
}
```

```php
// Author model

function albums()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Album::class);
}
```

There's a many-to-many relationship with Author and Contribution.

An author might have several contribution for an album.

```php
// Author model

public function contributions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Contribution::class)->withPivot('album_id');
}
```

```php
// Contribution model
public function authors()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Author::class)->withPivot('album_id');
}
```

As you can see, I use an additional field *"album_id"* on the pivot table album_author. I'm trying to use that field to get the contribution of an author for a given album.

In the author page, I'd like to list his albums and his contribution (per album).

```php
// Author controller
public function show($id)
{
  $author = Author::find($id);

  $albums = Album::whereHas('authors', function ($query) use ($id) {
      $query->where('authors.id', $id);
  })
      ->with('authors.contributions') // How to query the pivot "album_id" here ?
      ->get();

  return $albums;
}
```

How can I retrieve the contributions of the current author for an album ?
How to query the pivot "album_id" ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [wherePivot](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

```
 $albums = Album::whereHas('authors', function ($query) use ($id) {
      $query->where('authors.id', $id);
  })
      ->with(['authors.contributions'=>function($query)use($albumId){
      $query->wherePivot('album_id',albumId);}]) 
      ->get();

  return $albums;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried this yes and this is exactly the problem, I'm not able to get  $albumId